# laravel model relationship seems backwards compared to docs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

So I am setting up a one to one relationship between MyModel and the users table.

MyModel obviously has a user_id column to tie back to the users.

However - when i go to setup the relationship in MyModel I have to set it up in a way which seems backward!

This is in MyModel:

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
```

Why Am i having to set the opposite foreign and local keys... ? Am i missing something?

Comment: If MyModel has a `user_id` attribute, the relationship should be `belongsTo('App\User');`

Comment: hmm when reading the docs I somehow got that mixed up! 
you are right though - just tested and works! cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this

```
class MyModel  { 
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    } 
}


class User { 
    public function myModel()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\MyModel');
    } 
}
```

And that should work as intended (one to one) relationship

Comment: as commenter above stated - I see that now - for some reason while i was reading the docs I got it backwards! thanks tho! cheers!